# Gray screen after starting Node in Corda DemoBench

Tags: corda

I am new to Corda DemoBench and for some reason all I see is a dark gray screen (under Notary, etc. section) when I click the Start Node button. I have installed the application on two differnet Windows 10 PCs and no luck.

I am trying to follow the tutorial found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz3wWonWv-Y

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.[Screenshot of gray interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL1bV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install it myself on my Windows 10 and I have the same problem. The DemoBench has been [deprecated](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/demobench.html), the video you linked is from 2017. So, I think this tool is no more maintained by R3 and it is not the recommended tool to start learning Corda.

If you want to create a small network, I would recommend you use the [Network Bootstrapper](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/network-bootstrapper.html) instead. There is also a nice video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITMOiMzkX4I).